# Pandas reading mobile number as float datatype

Tags: pandas

When reading csv/xlsx file in Pandas, mobile number is read as float64.
mobile
6.133434e+11
6.123232e+10

How to read the mobile number in correct format.eg: 613343404304,61232323333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply `dtype` when reading the source file (csv format for example)

```
df = pd.read_csv("yourfile.csv", dtype={"phone_number": str})
```